# Как из отформатированной даты, вернуть её обратно к moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть дата:
`moment().format('L')`
, как вернуть её обратно к moment? 
Если есть другие варианты, чтобы прибавить дни, они тоже подойдут, но пожалуйста, без парсинга строки

Comment: Совсем без парсинга не выйдет. Просто он будет скрыт внутри функций вендора. Примеры есть в документации https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прибавление дат:

```js
const date = moment().format("L");

const date2 = moment(date, "L").add(valueDays, 'days').format("L");
```